# Saving part of OSM shapefile in QGIS as GeoJSON strips 'name' field to 25 characters long

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, geojson

I want to copy part of OSM data in ESRI Shapefile (downloaded from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/ukraine.html ) and save in in GeoJSON to style later in Tilemill.

After saving, I see that string values in 'name' column get truncated to be 25 letters long.
Any ideas how to overcome mentioned problem?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I've seen answers related to letters truncation (like here: [How to overcome field truncation when converting OSM to shapefile with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/how-to-overcome-field-truncation-when-converting-osm-to-shapefile-with-qgis#comment12045_9894)), but I am not sure if I can use that advice.

Comment: How are you saving the shapefile to GeoJSON?

Comment: First, I add osm shapefile as layer into qgis, then select part of rendered map, right click on layer and select "save selected as", then choose geojson.

Comment: shapefiles truncate field names (legacy) - use another format to eliminate this issue.

Comment: What would you suggest in my situation? Can I use raw OSM data and somehow prepare them for TileMill?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [files and databases types you can use in Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/adding-layers/), the best seems to be to import your OSM data in a PostGis database and connect this database directly to Tilemill.

On [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/), download the *.osm.pbf file for your area of interest. Then use [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to import this data in the PostGis database.

Comment: Going to try follow you suggestion, will get back with result.